# sql server data-driven subscription stop sending

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report running on hourly basis checking for new orders. It's working great however, I would like to only send the report if there at least one order. If the report is empty - I don't want to send the report at all.

To extend this, I would like to only send the report if there new orders.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a condition in your DDS query to check for the order time. If there are any orders in the past hour your query should return your result set otherwise return nothing.

For example, in your query add the following logic

```
 DECLARE @HoursAgo int
 SELECT Top 1 @HoursAgo = DateDiff('hh',getdate(), OrderTime) 
 FROM Orders 
 ORDER BY OrderTime DESC
```

In your query add the following clause

```
 WHERE @HoursAgo > 0
```

You might also want to add extra checks to make sure the order is from the current day.

Comment: Would this not still send empty report?

Comment: You do not place this in the report dataset. When you define your Data Driven subscription it asks you for a query that can be used to determine email recipients, format, etc. For each row returned from that query an subscription is processed and delivered. If the query returns no results no subscriptions are sent out.

Comment: To clarify.. I am referring to step 3 in that data-driven subscription creation process.

Answer (score -1):

There is a property of the RDL dataset called "noRows" that can display a custom message if the dataset doesn't have any rows returned.  It will still send the empty report, just with a special message.

If you want the subscription to not fire off the report then the only way I know of to do this is to check the row count of the select statement if your stored procedure and throw an error if the row count is zero.  Not an elegant way to pull this off but it will not send the report because the error happens on the T-SQL side and SSRS won't be able to render the report.

```
declare @rows int

select @rows = -1

<select statement here>

select @rows = @@rowcount

if ( @rows < 1 )
begin
    RAISERROR ('no rows returned', 11, 1 );
end
```

Comment: This is not necessary in data-driven subscriptions. You do not need to touch the report definition. Instead you modify the query that defines your subscription parameters

Comment: Correct, that is another way to handle it.